# How to share history between terminal tabs?

Tags: terminal, command-line, history

I generally find myself using two or three tabs in my Terminal on OS X.

A minor inconvenience is that, by default, the tabs don't share their command history.  So, searching for a previous command that I ran on another tab by typing `history | grep thingIamlooking for` does not find it.

Is there a way of forcing Terminal tabs to share history, or is there some other "***history_of_all_tabs***" command?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to share history amongst Terminal tabs only, but here is something that could help you.

The history is not something that is handled by your terminal but by your shell (bash, tcsh, zsh, etc.)

Here are some options that'll help you set up a shared history amongst all the terminal windows (the shell instances).

This should be put somewhere in your `.bashrc` file.

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  # no duplicate entries
export HISTSIZE=100000                   # big big history
export HISTFILESIZE=100000               # big big history
shopt -s histappend                      # append to history, don't overwrite it

# Save and reload the history after each command finishes
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: +.5 for good answer, +.5 for good grammar ;)

Comment: @Lifely's solution isn't working for me in El Capitan. At all. Even the max length of the history file. Is there a new solution since 2012? (I'd have commented above, but don't have the rep)

Comment: This is working for me (added in .bash_profile) in El Capitan with the addition of export SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0 in my .bash_profile and running: touch ~/.bash_sessions_disable

Comment: works great on Ubuntu 18.04 for bash

Comment: Please see this comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows#comment75601_1292 "The problem with this PROMPT_COMMAND solution is that the numbers for each history item changes after each command :(. For example if you type history and 1) ls 2) rm, then you do !1 to repeat 1, the history number might change and might run the rm command..."

Comment: Was this answer copied from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48113/19088 ?

Answer (score 3):

For **zsh** users, append the following to your `~/.zshrc` to share history between your terminals:

> ```bash
> # Appends every command to the history file once it is executed
> setopt inc_append_history
> # Reloads the history whenever you use it
> setopt share_history
> # (Nice to have) ignore consecutive duplicates in history
> setopt histignoredups
> ```

Taken from this blog post: [Sharing history in zsh - Markus Wein](https://nuclearsquid.com/writings/shared-history-in-zsh/)

Comment: To make this equivalent with the accepted answer, you can add `setopt histignoredups` to dedup the history.

Comment: I also had to add something like `export HISTSIZE=5000`